# How to display two date differences in year and months?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

This code returns difference between two dates like this `0.4876712328767123 5.933333333333334` but what I want it in a human readable format.

If the difference between two date is less than 1 year than I want to display only months like `5 months` and if the difference is more than 1 year then I want result like `1 year 6 months` .

How can I do it?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

        @property
        def date_period(self):
           if not self.end_date:
              self.end_date = timezone.now().date()
           period = self.end_date - self.start_date
           return '{0} {1}'.format(period.days/365, period.days/30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`datetutil.relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) for this. For example:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def date_period(self):
       if not self.end_date:
          self.end_date = timezone.now().date()
       period = relativedelta(self.end_date, self.start_date)
       if period.years > 0:
           return '{0} {1}'.format(period.years, period.months)
       return '{0}'.format(period.months)
```

Comment: How can I get month only  if year is equals to 0 or less than 1?

Comment: Well, you can add an if-else condition. I have updated the answer.